# Random ints with more specific range python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to design a basic Battleships style game, where the ship takes up 2 spaces on a 5x5 board.

I am randomly generating one of the co-ordinates and trying to randomly generate 2nd co-ordinate to be within 1 space of the last number. Here is my code

```
coordinate1x = random.randint(0,4)
coordinate1y = random.randint(0,4)
coordinate1 = [coordinate1x, coordinate1y]

coordinate2x = random.randint(coordinate1x, coordinate1x + 1)
coordinate2y = random.randint(coordinate1y, coordinate1y + 1)
coordinate2 = [coordinate2x, coordinate2y]

battleship_location = [coordinate1, coordinate2]
```

I am struggling to find the logic to get the correct numbers.

Any help is greatly apprecaited

Comment: You should probably allow it to generate a value one less than the first coordinates too. And cap the values for the second round of generation to the 0 to 4 range (so 4,4 can't be followed by 5,5, outside the board).

Comment: So the initial value goes to 0,3 so that it cant be outside of the 5x5 bounds?

Comment: No, you want the initial value to go anywhere. You bound the second round only.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean :( could you add the amended lines of code to help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two decisions to take:

1. whether to place the ship horizontally or vertically
2. where to place the first of the two cells on the grid.

The orientation of the ship can be:

```
[ ][ ]
```

or:

```
[ ]
[ ]
```

The left/top most of the two is the cell that is selected in the second choice. To make sure you don't overrun the border, the range that can be selected for the first cell, is like this for a horizontal ship (`Y` can be selected, `N` not):

```
Y Y Y Y N
Y Y Y Y N
Y Y Y Y N
Y Y Y Y N
Y Y Y Y N
```

For a vertical ship:

```
Y Y Y Y Y 
Y Y Y Y Y 
Y Y Y Y Y 
Y Y Y Y Y 
N N N N N
```

Here is the suggested code:

```
# choose whether to place the ship vertically or not
is_vertical = random.randint(0,1)
# choose the first cell from a range that depends on the chosen direction
cell1 = [random.randint(0, 3+is_vertical), random.randint(0,4-is_vertical)]
# copy the coordinates
cell2 = cell1[:]
# add 1 to the x or y coordinate, depending on the chosen direction 
cell2[is_vertical] += 1

battleship_location = [cell1, cell2]

print(battleship_location)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, never thought of determining whether it was vertical or not. Thank you so much for your help!!!